# How to get exactly position of the point in the image and not change in the other device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a image map not Google map in here [my image map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Ilu.jpg)

How can I detech the position of the red point in this image then I write code jquery for mouse over in this point and show popup message. In pc it ok but when I change to view in mobile it also change the position of the point. Please let me know how to set exactly the position of the red point and it not change position in mobile or tablet. This is my code jquery for getting the position of the point

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#test").click(function(e) {
     var offset = $(this).offset();
     var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
     var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
     alert('X: ' + relativeX + ', Y: ' + relativeY);
     $(".position").val("afaf");
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery we can make it so that on hover over a certain element, an element which was once invisible shows up, and as soon as the mouse moves away it dissapears. The code below should send you on the right direction.

https://jsfiddle.net/07q6pLfj/1/

```
<div>
    <p>This is an element which does not change when you hover over it.</p>
        <div class="hover"><div class="popup">
        This is text which pops up when you hover
    </div>
        When you hover over this a popup shows.
</div>

.popup {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
        background-color: red;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
        margin-top: 30px;
}


$(".hover").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".popup").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".popup").hide();
});
```

Comment: In my problem is a point in the image not a text so I difficult with set exactly this point when hover in mobile and tablet

Comment: if thats the case then good luck. you may be able to add a meta tag which stops resizing but I don't know how effective it will be. Also using an image is probably one of the worst ways to go about it, and even on different sized desktop computers, it will break.